# Dplyr e gsub: como substituir trechos de uma coluna por outra

Tags: r, dplyr

Tenho o seguinte data-frame:

```
xis <- data.frame(x1=c("**alo.123", "**alo.132", "**alo.199"), x2=c("sp", "mg", "rj"), x3=c(NA))
```

Eu gostaria de criar uma nova coluna, utilizando o gsub da seguinte maneira:

```
x3[1] <- gsub("alo", xis$x2[1], xis$x1[1])
x3[2] <- gsub("alo", xis$x2[2], xis$x1[2])
x3[3] <- gsub("alo", xis$x2[3], xis$x1[3])
```

Não gostaria de usar o for e sei que há a possibilidade de usar o maply para isso, como, por exemplo:

```
xis$x3 <- mapply(gsub,"alo", xis$x2, xis$x1)
```

Haveria uma forma de usar o `mutate` do dplyr para isso? Algo do tipo:

```
xis <- mutate(xis, x3 = gsub("alo", x2, x1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não dá para usar diretamente assim porque o `gsub` não é vetorizado, então será utilizado apenas o primeiro elemento do replacement, substituindo tudo por `sp`.

O que o `mapply`está fazendo é vetorizar a função, e você poderia usar o próprio `mapply` dentro do `mutate` sem problemas:

```
xis <- mutate(xis, x3 = mapply(gsub, "alo", x2, x1))
xis
         x1 x2       x3
1 **alo.123 sp **sp.123
2 **alo.132 mg **mg.132
3 **alo.199 rj **rj.199
```

Na resposta do Daniel, a função `str_replace` do `stringr` está basicamente fazendo isso, vetorizando o `sub` com o `mapply`. E a `str_replace_all` está vetorizando o `gsub` com `mapply`.

Se você quiser, você pode criar suas próprias função vetorizadas com o `mapply` ou com o `Vectorize`(um wrapper do `mapply`) antes de usar dentro do `mutate`. Por exemplo:

```
gsub2<-Vectorize(gsub) # vetoriza o gsub 
xis <- mutate(xis, x3 = gsub2("alo", x2, x1))
xis
         x1 x2       x3
1 **alo.123 sp **sp.123
2 **alo.132 mg **mg.132
3 **alo.199 rj **rj.199
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `str_replace` do pacote `stringr` assim:

```
require(stringr)
xis <- data.frame(x1=c("**alo.123", "**alo.132", "**alo.199"), x2=c("sp", "mg", "rj"), x3=c(NA))
xis  <- mutate(xis, x3 = str_replace(string = x1, pattern = "alo", replacement = x2))
xis
         x1 x2       x3
1 **alo.123 sp **sp.123
2 **alo.132 mg **mg.132
3 **alo.199 rj **rj.199
```